# How to install module tf0to1 in python3.5 operating system windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to upgrade vactorized_graph.py using below command which gives me an error

```
C:\Python35>python tf_upgrade.py --infile vectorized_graph.py --outfile 
vectorized_graph_1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tf_upgrade.py", line 21, in <module>
from tf0to1.core import Tensorflow0To1Transformer
```

ImportError: No module named 'tf0to1'

and when I try to install module tf0to1, I get below error.

```
C:\Python35\Scripts>pip3 install tf0to1
Collecting tf0to1
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tf0to1 (from 
  versions: )
  No matching distribution found for tf0to1
```

(I have already installed module redbaron)

Any suggestion?